# How to emulate the inputView behavior with a subView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipickerview, inputview

I have a tableView with prototype cells. It loads the cell data based on a chosen date. I want to have a button (UIBarButton or UIButton) that displays a datePicker with the same behavior as an inputView from a UITextField (e.g the birthday datePicker on the Contacts app).

I found this solution: [How do I make a modal date picker that only covers half the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484147/how-do-i-make-a-modal-date-picker-that-only-covers-half-the-screen) but that is for tapping a UITextField and not a UIButton.

Is there a way to display an inputView from a button tap? If not, how can I emulate the same behavior for a PickerView?

Thanks in advance,

Juliano

Comment: I know [this isn't quite what you want](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298378/ipad-custom-size-of-modal-view-controller), but you might be able to tweak it to make it work?