# UIDatePicker in UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uidatepicker

I am making a small program and I ran into a small problem. I need to pop up a UIDatePicker in my UITableViewController. Any help will be appreciated. I want the UIPickerView to appear when a button is pressed. I wanted the UIPickerView to be hidden and when the user presses the button it becomes visible. But since I can't place the UIDatePicker in my UITableViewController that can't happen. Is there another way?

Comment: You need to be more specific. When should the date picker appear? How? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to enter my UIDatePicker into the storyboard in my UITableViewController.

Comment: That doesn't explain when or how you want the picker to appear. Your question can't be answered in its current form. It is too vague.

Comment: you can add datepicker on one uiview and display it on button tapped

Comment: @AbhijitChaudhari Do you mean a container view?

Comment: @Abdullah Shafique yes

Comment: @AbhijitChaudhari I tried to add a container to my table view but it won't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484147/how-do-i-make-a-modal-date-picker-that-only-covers-half-the-screen pls check this?

Comment: @Abdullah Shafique you need to create one view controller add uitableview on it and then add uiview

Comment: @AbhijitChaudhari I wish I could. I am using static cells and I can not do that unless in a UITableViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution! I decided to create the UIDatePicker with my code. I used:

```
dtpPicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
dtpPicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 162);
[self.view addSubview:dtpPicker];
```

Thanks for everyone who helped me!

Answer (score 0):

`[self.tableView addSubview:dtpPicker];` if `tableview`in view.