# Mixed UIPicker & TextField in TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield, uipickerview

I've setup a TableView with 4 UITextFields that I want the user to be able to input some information into. 2 of the text fields when pressed need to present a UIPickerView to select an option, instead of the keyboard. Each PickerView needs to display a separate array of items.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? This is the closest i've come to finding a solution:

[How to use one UIPickerView for multiple textfields in one view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612460/how-to-use-one-uipickerview-for-multiple-textfields-in-one-view)

I can get the Picker to show up correctly but only show an one array and every text field in the cell shows the same picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love this answer, which is why I link to it when I can:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8583703/220820

You could fill your picker with data whenever a text field becomes first responder for its inputView (its keyboard replacement).

Answer (score 0):

Andreas's answer is better or you could do present UIPickers embedded in UIActionSheets from the bottom and after selection, you could use the picker's delegate method to set the TextField text.